# "stray shower" mean

Tags: phrase-meaning, listening

I heard this on a radio forecast:

> ....could see a *stray* shower.

If I heard it correctly, what does a stray shower truly mean?

Appreciate if someone can describe what a stray shower or thunderstorm would be like!

Comment: You sure it was "straight" and not a similar-sounding word like "strange" or "late"?

Comment: @Andrew yeah, I would not expect a strange shower from a weather broadcast. I'm sure it's not the word *late*. Maybe, it's a strain, strained or stray shower? It seems that stray shower make more sense here.

Comment: @Andrew yeah, I also found this in a dictionary: *There is a 20 percent chance of precipitation, with a stray shower or thunderstorm possible in the afternoon.* can you describe a little bit on what a stray shower or thunderstorm would be like? Maybe in an answer? Thanks!

Comment: You most certainly heard _stray_, not _straight_. "Stray showers" is commonly-heard in forecasts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree you probably heard "*stray* shower".

"Stray" (adj). depending on context, means *occasional, possible, isolated*, and/or *brief*.

> The sky was a perfect blue that day, with the occasional **stray** cloud wandering by.
>
> We do log a few **stray** attempts to hack the server each day, but none ever get past the firewall.

A "stray shower" would mean a little bit of rain here and there, but nothing serious or long-lasting.  Of course, every region has a different notion of what might be "a little bit" of rain.

Comment: What will be the difference between a scattered shower and a stray shower?

Comment: @dan  Not really a lot.   It depends on context.  *Scattered* means more *here and there* while *stray* means more *occasional* ... but still that's kind of my opinion.  It's not anything official.

Comment: @Dan, a scattered shower may be one of a number of showers in the area; a stray shower might not be.

Comment: RE: _scattered_ vs. _stray_: I wonder if a "stray shower" is a popular layman's term for an [isolated shower](http://www.wafb.com/story/6488329/isolated-vs-scattered-showers).

Comment: @J.R.  For me it's a sort of picturesque metaphor.  A *stray* shower is like a *stray* cat that, for no reason, wanders over to where you are, rubs itself all over everything, howls for attention, and then suddenly wanders off because it feels like leaving.  *Scattered* showers are more like a herd of buffalo, dotting the open plain here and there.